# Dequeue scripts in IE7 only using functions.php

Tags: functions, javascript

Is it possible to dequeue scripts in IE7 only using functions.php? I have my scripts configured in the following way:

```
// JS
function scripts() {
  // Register scripts & styles
  wp_register_script( 'responsive_nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/responsive-nav.js', '', '', false );
  wp_register_script( 'initialize_lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/initialize_lightbox.js', 'jquery', '', true );
  wp_register_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', 'jquery', '', true );
  wp_register_style( 'lightbox_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css', array(), '', 'all' );

  // Enqueue
  wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive_nav' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'initialize_lightbox' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox_styles' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts' );
```

Thanks!

Squid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has built-in browser detection mechanism. And they set a global variable `$is_IE`.

```
function scripts()
{
    global $is_IE;
    if( ! $is_IE ){
        // Register scripts & styles
        // Enqueue
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great way to check which version of IE you facing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042194/915636

As for the part about deregistering scripts..

**here is an example:**

```
$browser = get_browser();

if($browser->browser == 'IE' && $browser->majorver == 6) {
    // DO NOTHING
} elseif($browser->browser == 'IE' && $browser->majorver == 7) {
    wp_deregister_style('some_script_id');
    wp_dequeue_style('some_script_id');
}
```